# how do I read posted json data in C# WebAPI?

Tags: c#, json, extjs, asp.net-web-api, http-post

ExtJS call: `record.save();`does `POST api/saveEntry`

Firebug shows POST data is sent: http://pl.vc/26tre

but

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public Dictionary<string,string> SaveEntry(EntryModel entry=null)
```

throws error (code 500) that EntryModel type can't be processed,

```
public Dictionary<string,string> SaveEntry(string entry=null)
```

has `(entry == null)` and

```
public Dictionary<string,string> SaveEntry(HttpRequestMessage req=null)
```

has `(req==null)`.

Is there a way to get the json data?

Comment: Well, I have never used `AcceptVerbs` but I think that with this - `[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]` you are restricting the action to only accept `GET` requests. So if indeed you use `POST` to send the data back to the server this may cause the error. Just for the try - remove all attributes (if possible) or just the second  `[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]` and see if that fix the problem.

Comment: If you use HttpRequestMessage as an input parameter you should not use a default value.  There is always an incoming HttpRequestMessage.